# cvtColor fails assertion scn == 3 || scn ==4, but the image does have 3 channels and exists

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, pygame, webcam

I'm trying to run face detection on a Raspberry Pi, so I'm trying to find the fastest way to do everything. (every millisecond counts on a 700MHz processor!)

I made a quick speedtest that timed out the various options I need to check, which are:

- Get webcam picture (choices are pygame.camera or openCV's cv2.VideoCapture)
- Resize, convert to grayscale, and (if needed) convert to numpy and rotate.

It sounds odd, but for capturing a picture, pygame.camera is about 60ms faster than openCV on the raspberry pi.

Assuming that the extra conversion from a pygame surface to numpy, plus the 90 degree rotation, takes less than 60ms, it would be worth it to go with a mix.

The issue here is that I'm getting an odd cvtColor error, claiming my numpy ndarray (the backend for opencv 2.0 at the moment) does not have 3 or 4 channels.

This is odd, because I print out the shape of the ndarray right before I call cvtColor, and it has 3 channels. I can only assume I'm missing something incredibly obvious.

Here's the pared down code.

```
import pygame
import cv2
import numpy
from pygame import camera

pygame.init()
pygame.camera.init()

#get one shot from pygame camera
cam_list = pygame.camera.list_cameras()
pywebcam = pygame.camera.Camera(cam_list[0],(640,480))
pywebcam.start()
image = pywebcam.get_image()

for z in xrange(50):
    image = pywebcam.get_image()

pywebcam.stop()

if image:
    #numpy (convert to numpy as fast as possible)
    numpy_image=pygame.surfarray.array3d(image)

    print(numpy_image.shape)
    numpy_image=cv2.cvtColor(numpy_image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    numpy_image = cv2.resize(numpy_image, (0,0), fx=0.25, fy=0.25)
    numpy_image = numpy.rot90(numpy_image,3)
```

EDIT: Removed a bunch of code. The new code has removed all the profiling.

The output I get from this program is:

```
Average time in range: 58.64 ms.

Pausing to ensure webcam is freed.

Average time in range: 115.56 ms.

(480, 640, 3)
Pure NumPy
  0     ms to printing shape.
  39    ms to convert to grayscale.
  16    ms to resize.
  0     ms to rotate.
  58 total ms.

(640, 480, 3)
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in cvtColor, file /build/opencv-XZa2gn/opencv-2.3.1/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp, line 2834
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "profile.py", line 72, in <module>
    numpy_image=cv2.cvtColor(numpy_image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: /build/opencv-XZa2gn/opencv-2.3.1/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:2834: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cvtColor
```

What's going on here?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the [minimal](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) amount of code that reproduces your problem. It's hard to look at a wall of text and figure out where the problem lies. For example, nothing related to `simpleProfiler` is related to the error you get (unless something *very* strange is happening). It would be better if you could trim your answer to a few lines of code where your problem still exists.

Comment: Got it, done. Sorry about that, didn't look like that much when I was putting it in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer. Apparently, numpy doesn't actually update the ndarray when you work on them, it just holds temporary changes in mind. Things are nice and fast that way.

While the C++ version of opencv 2.0 can handle that, the python bindings cannot- and since pygame's surfarray code works off numpy, any sort of situation where you go pygame->opencv is going to hit that problem.

With that said, all you need to do is call numpy.copy() after you call pygame.surfarray.array3d().

The new copy will have none of these temporary changes. For that reason, don't bother with array3d(), just use pixels3d()- you have to make a copy anyway, so don't make two.

For more information, I think the temporary changes were called 'strides' or something of the sort.